# Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given

Tags: php

I have the below piece of code which checks the given key exists in the array. But when executing this code I get this error:

> "Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given". I am new to PHP and no idea what causes this error.

#### Code

```
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($connection, $id, FT_UID);

if (array_key_exists('parts', $structure))
{

};
```

Comment: Second Argument should be array. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php.here your function not return array

Comment: `$strucuture` doesn't contain what you think it does. Or what you expect it to.

Comment: Not a real question. The error message clearly states what's wrong, so make sure your $structure is an array.

Comment: `var_dump($structure)` will tell u the answer

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To protect against someone passing a boolean or null into the function, you can add a simple check to see if `$structure` is an array before using it:

```
    if (is_array($structure) && array_key_exists('parts', $structure))
    {
       //...magic stuff here 
    }
```

The simple answer to 'why' your original code is broken is that  imap_fetchstructure() isn't finding the requested message and toand returning a `false`, `null`, or `0`.  The documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php doesn't indicate what's returned on failure, but it's easy to guess.  Most php functions that return objects but are unable to complete return a null or false on failure (when I say failure I don't mean error or an exception, just couldn't do or find whatever you asked of it).

Comment: This might be the way for building a library, but in this case it's much more important to know *why* it's not an array / object.

Comment: Thankx. I think this one worked.

Comment: `when I say failure I don't mean error or an exception, just couldn't do or find whatever you asked of it`  Same difference to me.

Comment: Logical conditions pass or fail.  If you ask to verify a logical statement and it fails instead of passing, it's not an language or runtime error or exception of any kind--it simply a failed logical evaluation, which is completely valid.  Calling a non-existing array indexes isn't proper and throws legitimate PHP Error log notice that something isn't kosher. PHP Errors and Exceptions are legitimate concepts that have specific meanings that should only be used to refer to Errors (Critical, warnings, notices, etc...) and code thrown exceptions. 'My statement Error'd' != 'My statement failed'

Comment: Be sure you're not setting `$structure` to something that doesn't exist. Also `is_array($structure)` has to be before the `array_key_exists`, as it is in this accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing `imap_fetchstructure()` is returning false, meaning the function fails to complete your desired task. To debug, see what `print_r($structure);` outputs.

Comment: From what I can tell, [imap_fetchstructure](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php) returns an object, I don't see anything in the reference to indicate it returns FALSE on failure. I'm unfamiliar with it though...

Comment: I've checked the docs too, but still clearly PHP is telling the contents of `$structure` isn't an array. So `false` would be most-likely the result.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP documentation says it will return an object, however if you view the PHP source code you'll see it actually returns FALSE on failure, and only returns an object if everything succeeds.

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/imap/php_imap.c#L2280