# array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, wordpress, array-key-exists

My Wordpress page (yarnhk.com) appears the following lines:

> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string
>   given in
>   /home/yarnhrnm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/fusion-core/shortcodes/class-fullwidth.php
>   on line 482
>
> Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string
>   given in
>   /home/yarnhrnm/public_html/wp-content/plugins/fusion-core/shortcodes/class-fullwidth.php
>   on line 483

The fullwidth.php file line 482 & 483 show as follows:

```
if ( ( array_key_exists( 'backgroundattachment', $args ) 
   && $args['backgroundattachment'] == 'scroll' ) 
   || ( array_key_exists( 'background_attachment', $args ) 
   && $args['background_attachment'] == 'scroll' )
```

Any help here?

Comment: What is the output of this: `var_dump($args);`

Comment: This page should be:http://yarnhk.com/home-3/

Comment: To tunananh, sorry that I do not quite understand your meaning....

Comment: `$args` needs to be an array. Is it an array? `array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array` - it tells you right there. The chances are (the issue *is*), `$args` is not an array. put the code @tuananh gave you under the code you provided in your question and tell us what it returns

Comment: The error is clear enough: You have to provide an array, and AREN'T

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: array\_key\_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747066/warning-array-key-exists-expects-parameter-2-to-be-array-boolean-given)

Answer (score 0):

> parameter 2 to be array, string given

The error message says, that your `$args` is not an array but a normal string. Look for the definition of the variable (and - of course - for any accident overwriting).

You should use `var_dump($args);` to output the type and the value of `$args`.

Comment: Does it mean like this:if ( ( array_key_exists( 'backgroundattachment', var_dump($args); ) && $args['backgroundattachment'] == 'scroll' ) ||
     ( array_key_exists( 'background_attachment', var_dump($args); ) && $args['background_attachment'] == 'scroll' )
   )

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have made it with the following codes:

```
if( is_array($args) && ( array_key_exists( 'backgroundattachment', $args ) && $args['backgroundattachment'] == 'scroll' ) || is_array($args) && ( array_key_exists( 'background_attachment', $args ) && $args['background_attachment'] == 'scroll' )) { 
    // Something
}
```

Done!